# ms-access: displaying column as "something else"

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

i have the following access sql statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT [Occurrence Number], [Occurrence Date], [1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)], [Cup Type], NULL as '2 0 Analytical (Testing Phase)', [2 0 Area], NULL,NULL FROM [Lab Occurrence Form] 
WHERE NOT ([1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)] IS NULL)
```

in this: `NULL as '2 0 Analytical (Testing Phase)'` when it displays the column it shows the single quote. if i remove the quote completely it gives me an error, if i use double quotes it shows me the double quotes in the resulting table

is it possible to not have it show any quotes?

Comment: Your query appears to be incomplete. The parentheses don't match.

Comment: I'll say it again, you're really shooting yourself in the foot with such horrendly-named fields and tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use square brackets around column names and single quotes around strings. Try using square brackets instead:

```
NULL as [2 0 Analytical (Testing Phase)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use same syntax as you have

```
NULL as [2 0 Analytical (Testing Phase)]
```